# How to zoom to Feature in VB .net

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, features, vb.net, zoom

I'm trying to zoom to a feature just like in Arcmap but in VB.net.
I'm using Axmapcontrol to display the map.
I've tried the following:

```
Dim pCmdItem As ICommandItem
Dim pUID As New UID
pUID.Value = "{AB073B49-DE5E-11D1-AA80-00C04FA37860}"
pCmdItem = CommandBars.Find(pUID)
pCmdItem.Execute()
```

but it's showing the following error:

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

I've found a solution that suggets to change mytype from empty to WindowsForms in the vbproj file, but it already contains the correct value.
Is there any way to zoom to a feature in an Axmapcontrol in VB.net?

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach, you build the extent you want to zoom to by cycling through the selection. The following VBA function takes as input an `ILayer` object.

```vb
Public Sub ZoomToSelected(ByRef pLayer As ILayer)

    If TypeOf pLayer Is IFeatureLayer Then
        ' Get selection on layer
        Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
        Set pFeatureLayer = pLayer
        Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
        Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer

        If pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count > 0 Then
            ' Layer has a selection so process it
            Dim pEnvelope As IEnvelope
            Set pEnvelope = New Envelope
            pEnvelope.SetEmpty
            Dim pFeature As IFeature

            ' Create a cursor over selection
            Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
            pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Search Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor
            Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
            Dim pEnv As IEnvelope

            ' Loop unioning extents
            Do While Not pFeature Is Nothing
                Set pEnv = pFeature.Extent
                pEnvelope.Union pEnv
                Set pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
            Loop

            ' Get active view an reset extent
            Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
            Set pMXD = ThisDocument
            Dim pMap As IMap
            Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap
            Dim pAV As IActiveView
            Set pAV = pMap
            pAV.Extent = pEnvelope
            pAV.Refresh
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You may want to tweak the code to expand the extent before you set the Activeview to it. That can be done via the `IEnvelope` interface